# delete 'nan' rows and not "NaN" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to delete the rows that contains 'nan%' in in the 'Precison' and 'Recall' columns,
as below image shows,

[image]

I just need to remove all rows that shows 'nan%' both in 'Precision' and in 'Recall'.
dropna() does not work here.

Comment: It worked, but the dropna() deletes all rows that contain NaN,
I need to delete the rows only if both 'Precision' and 'Recall' are NaN'

Answer (score 2):

You can select all rows if not equal `nan%` in both columns:

```
df[df[['Precison','Recall']].ne('nan%').all(axis=1)]
```

Or you can replace all `nan%` to `NaN` for working [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = df.replace('nan%', np.nan).dropna(subset=['Precison','Recall'])
```

Comment: I get the same result that I got before.

Comment: @oddodd - What is `print (df.head().to_dict(orient='list'))` ?